# Monitor losing signal on Ubuntu/Kubuntu 18.04 LTS/20.04 LTS/ 20.10 and Manjaro xfce and kde plasma on AMD RX 580 8GB GPU

Tags: boot, drivers, kubuntu, radeon, nomodeset

As the title specifies I tried to install all the ubuntu/kubuntu and Manjaro xfce or kde plasma based versions mentioned and all of them have the same issues with my rx 580. When I start the installation my monitor loses signal. The only way to fix this is to boot with "safe graphics" and to finish the installation. After finishing the installation and restarting the issue pops up again and this time it's fixable by adding the command -nomodeset in the grub menu but with it I have very low performance in any game and even slightly lagging while doing media playback. I tried installing the open source drivers (mesa) and removing nomodeset and the issue persists, then I tried the proprietary drivers and removed nomodeset once again and the monitor still loses signal. I tried with both csm and uefi, secure boot is disabled, I tried even with the network stack disabled on my motherboard (msi b550 mortar max) and I tried multiple bios versions and still no result.. Does anyone have a solution? Windows works fine.

My full specs in case it helps.

- Ryzen 5 2600 cpu
- 16gb ram adata xpg ram (8x2 running in dual channel)
- Msi b550 mortar wifi motherboard
- rx 580 8gb gpu from xfx.

Thank you in advance